# SQL Azure - Max row size exceeded error at Standard 50 DTU but same query has no error at Premium 150 DTU

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Interested if anyone knows about what could be going on under the hood to cause the same query to fail at one Azure SQL performance level but work at a higher level?

The query does max out the server to 100% at the Standard level, but I would expect to get an out of memory related exception if this was the issue. But instead I get a

> Cannot create a row of size 8075 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

I am aware that the query needs to be optimized, but what I am interested in for the purposes of this question is what about bumping up to Premium 150DTU would suddenly make the same data not exceed the max row size?

Answer (score 1):

I can make an educated guess as to what your problem is.  When you change from one reservation size to another, the resources available to the optimizer changes.  It believes it has more memory, specifically.  Memory is a key component in costing queries in the query optimizer.  The plan choice happening in the lower reservation size likely has a spool or sort that is trying to create an object in tempdb.  The one in the higher reservation size is not.  This it hitting a limitation in the storage engine since the intermediate table can not be materialized.

Without looking at the plan, it is not possible to say with certainty whether this is a requirement of the chosen query plan or merely an optimization.  However, you can try using the NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL hint on the query to see if that makes it work on the smaller reservation size.  (Given that it has less memory, I will guess that it is not the issue, however).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017

(Now I am guessing with general advice since I don't know what kind of app you have but it based on the normal patterns I see regularly):
If your schema is really wide or poorly defined, please consider revising your table definition to reduce the size of the columns to the right minimum.  For data warehousing applications, please consider using dimension tables + surrogate keys.  If you are dumping text log files into SQL and then trying to distinct them, note that distinct is often going to imply a sort which could lead to this kind of issue if the row is too wide (as you are trying to use all columns in the key).

Best of luck on getting your app to work.  SQL tends to work very well for you for relational apps where you think through the details of your schema and indexes a bit.  In the future, please post a bit more detail about your query patterns, schema, and query plans so others can help you more precisely.